# Ember data, how to get max id for store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to query the ember data store to find the max id for a given model? I know I could find all, walk through the objects, store ids when they are greater than the previous, etc, etc.

I'm new to Ember, I'm used to being able to call aggregate methods on database, you know, max(), min(), sum() all that stuff. There HAS to be a way to do this in ember, right? I have searched and searched, I'm honestly a little mystified that I can't find anything for what has to be a very common use-case.

I'm currently using fixtures, want to add a new line to an order. When I create the new record I need to find the max id of all other records so I can increment it for the new record.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do this. Ember Data should assign an ID to new records. At least on some versions of Ember Data, I believe it will actually complain if you include your own ID in the new record.

Comment: Why would you need to manually increment it?

Comment: Currently I'm using fixtures like I said, when I add a new orderline item to my store it gets an ID like 'fixture0'.

Comment: My model supports multiple orders, with one or more orderlines per order. A click on a page button adds an orderline and it needs to be associated to the parent order. I guess the fixture0 would work, but it's pretty ugly especially if used in the URL.

The need to increment is because you get the max id in the table before creating a new record, then create a new record with maxid + 1. This is a very common pattern in server-side development where I have most of my experience. 

Maybe what I'm doing isn't very "Ember-ish", that's a challenge for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ember (and web applications in general) don't communicate with a database directly.

It's easy enough to calculate the next id for your fixtures:

```
let ids = models.mapBy('id');
let nextId = Math.max(...ids) + 1;
```

Or you could use [ember-cli-mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) in your tests which takes care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly easier than the way I was initially thinking. I don't have a lot of JS under my belt yet, I forget about the map function sometimes.